# Javascript - Rewrite anonymous function to named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/codrops/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery) polaroid-gallery code on my web page.
On the particular site I have placed the polaroid-gallery code **inside** a [Slide Out Panel](https://jsfiddle.net/w4b94g1a/). I keep getting the following error in the console when polaroid-gallery code is placed inside the Slide Out Panel:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined photostack.js:54 
shuffleMArray photostack.js:325 
moveItems photostack.js:390 
Photostack._shuffle photostack.js:263 
Photostack._showPhoto photostack.js:166 
Photostack._open photostack.js:180 
Photostack._initEvents photostack.js:130 
Photostack._init photostack.js:99 
Photostack (index):431 
(anonymous function)
```

I have noticed that I do not get this error in the console when the polaroid-gallery code is placed **outside** the Slide Out Panel. (everything works as expected)

I am a noob when it comes to JavaScript, but I have figured that the JS which calls the polaroid-gallery is an anonymous functions that are created at runtime. It seems like this anonymous function is not running when the polaroid-gallery is inside the Slide Out Panel - so I think I somehow will have to rewrite the anonymous functions to a named function in order to get the code to run from within the Slide Out Panel. **Please correct me if I am wrong!**

This is the original code: (anonymous functions)

```
 new Photostack( document.getElementById( 'photostack-3' ), {
        callback : function( item ) {
            console.log(item)
        }
    } );
```

This is my named function attempt: (**not working - I need help!**)

```
function Photostack()
{
    document.getElementById( 'photostack-3' ), {
    callback : function( item ) {
        console.log(item)
    }
}

Photostack();
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Well the very first thing to know is that if you call *your* function "Photostack", you'll *hide* the name of the library you're trying to use.

Comment: no, the usage of named vs unnamed function is not your problem here. And your second attempt is entirely gone wrong.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of what you're trying to do?

Comment: maybe var photostack = new Photostack(.....  is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `Photostack` on containers with non-zero size. Elements hidden with `display: none` have zero size.

Some lines of the [photostack code](https://github.com/codrops/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/blob/master/js/photostack.js) in execution order.

line 410: `this.sizes.*` are set to `offset*`, which are zero for hidden elements.
line 285: `columns = Math.ceil(this.sizes.inner.height * ...` which is 0
line 299: `var grid = []` and then nothing is added to array cause `columns` is 0
line 325: `grid = shuffleMArray(grid);`
line   54: `inArrLen = marray[0].length`, where `marray` is local name for `grid`, which is `[]`.

`([])[0].length` → `(undefined).length` → `Error!`

PS: You'd be able to do such *research* by yourself, if you'd use `break on errors` feature in dev.tools and walk around the stack.

Comment: So there is no way to wait for the particular panel to be sat to display:block before the JS is executed?

Comment: You can use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track changes in styles, but this method doesn't work in all browsers.